# url for highlight in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

The query for getting data using elastic search and highlighting is this

```
GET /autocomplete_test/doc/_search
{
     "size": 10,
     "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": {
              "query": "lor",
              "operator": "and"
           }
        }
     },
     "highlight": { 
       "fields": { 
       "_all":{} 
      } 
    }
}
```

This query returns the data that I want exactly correct but when I use this url

```
  GET /autocomplete_test/doc/_search/?q=lor&highlight=(fields:_all)&pretty=True
```

it does not return the highlight in the response so what do I need to write in the url to get the correct response as I am getting from the query?

Comment: Hi, this could be helpful for you, no? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195017/different-result-when-using-get-post-in-elastic-search you could send your query like it's described in accepted answer

Comment: I'd go as @EvaldasBuinauskas said, i.e. inline your query in the URL using the `?source=...` parameter, because the `highlight` parameter is not supported.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas - I was looking for the exact thing. Thanks for directing me to the correct answer. It worked smooth.