# Send object with axios get request

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I want to send a get request with an object. The object data will be used on the server to update session data. But the object doesn't seem to be sent correctly, because if I try to send it back to print it out, I just get:

`" N; "`

I can do it with jQuery like this and it works:

```
 $.get('/mysite/public/api/updatecart', { 'product': this.product },  data => {     
              console.log(data);
           });
```

The object is sent back from server with laravel like this:

```
public function updateCart(Request $request){
      return serialize($request->product);
```

The same thing doesn't work with axios:

```
axios.get('/api/updatecart', { 'product': this.product })       
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
            });
```

I set a default baseURL with axios so the url is different. It reaches the api endpoint correctly and the function returns what was sent in, which was apparently not the object. I only get "**N;** " as result.

Comment: Can it be that you exceed the maximum length of the Query String?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

[**Axios API**](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config) is a bit different from the jQuery AJAX one. If you have to pass some params along with GET request, you need to use `params` property of `config` object (the second param of `.get()` method):

```
axios.get('/api/updatecart', {
  params: {
    product: this.product
  }
}).then(...)
```

You can pass either a plain object or a URLSearchParams object as `params` value.

Note that here we're talking about params appended to URL (query params), which is explicitly mentioned in the documentation.

If you want to send something within request **body** with GET requests, `params` won't work - and neither will `data`, as it's only taken into account for PUT, POST, DELETE, and PATCH requests. There're [several](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/1912) [lengthy](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/787) [discussions](https://github.com/rotki/rotki/issues/576) about this feature, and here's the telling quote:

> Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be an axios problem. The problem
> seems to lie on the http client implementation in the browser
> javascript engine.
>
> According to the documentation and the spec **XMLHttpRequest ignores the
> body of the request in case the method is GET**. If you perform a
> request in Chrome/Electron with XMLHttpRequest and you try to put a
> json body in the send method this just gets ignored.
>
> Using fetch which is the modern replacement for XMLHtppRequest also
> seems to fail in Chrome/Electron.

Until it's fixed, the only option one has within a browser is to use POST/PUT requests when data just doesn't fit into that query string. Apparently, that option is only available if corresponding API can be modified.

However, the most prominent case of GET-with-body - ElasticSearch `_search` API - actually does support both GET and POST; the latter seems to be far less known fact than it should be. Here's the [related SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195017/different-result-when-using-get-post-in-elastic-search).

Comment: The way it actually worked for me was using "data" instead "params". My example using async/await instead of then/catch:
`try { const res = await axios.get("/api/updatecart", { data: { product: this.product } }) } catch (error) { console.log(error) }`

Comment: @TelmoTrooper's way is the one that actually worked for me, not the original answer which does not actually send the parameters in the request body

Comment: This actually doens't work, the params config option is always put into the URL as query parameters as specified in [the docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).

Also we can [check for another ways](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/787) to do so, but of them did work for me.

Comment: @FilipeBezerradeSousa Thanks for the documentation link. I was trying to make a GET request with a plain text body (using `data`), and it didn't work. Had to rewrite as a POST request instead.

Comment: When you do this, make sure you pass 'params', because it's a property of the config object. Please see the config (AxiosRequestConfig) interface for more options.