# I'm trying to send a request from frontend React project to backend (I created both), works on postman but I'm getting an error in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

On my API I created the endpoint http://XX.XXX.XX.XX/api/v1/endpoint
which receives this string :

```
{
    "user": "RANDOM USER",
    "url": "RANDOM URL",
    "keyWord": "RANDOM KEYWORD"
}
```

and returns a result.
It works GREAT on postman but on the frontend part of the project I'm getting an error, and I can't seem to figure out why.
At first I thought that it has something to do with authentication but I changed the API so there is no need to be signed in anymore, but it still doesn't work on the react project. (works in postman though).
This is the error:

[image: error]

This is the frontend code:

```
import axios from 'axios';


 const user = "RANDOM USER";
 const url = "RANDOM URL";
 const keyWord = "RANDOM KEYWORD";

  const test = async () => {
    const details = JSON.stringify({
      user,
      url,
      keyWord,
    });

    try {
      await axios
        .get('http://XX.XXX.XX.XX/api/v1/endpoint', details, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.response) {
            // console.log(details); //WORKS
            console.log(err.response.data.error);
          }
        });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

This is the backend code:

```
exports.test = catchError(async (req, res, next) => { //catchError is an outer function with try-catch, it catches errors and it works fine
  const { url, keyWord } = await req.body;

  const response = await axios.get(url);
  const html = await response.data;

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      'XXXX'
    }
  });
```

Any ideas? Please help!

Comment: Pleas see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific, _concise_ question. Don't tell your whole story.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send object with axios get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404051/send-object-with-axios-get-request)