# Data sent from frontend turns null in backend

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, axios, backend

I have a problem - when trying to send data from frontend to backend, it does access the relevant controller/function in backend code, but all values become null, when I try to debug it.

The project I am working on was started by a third-party freelancers, and when I am creating new controllers/functions, I am using the same approach as they did. However, there is a problem with one case, and I can't find what exactly is different here, that this specific function isn't working.

For simplicity, I am testing it with just some random data, just to see if controller can get values sent from react.

**Frontend code:**

```
export const fetchToken = createAsyncThunk(
"tokens/fetchToken",
async (terminals: any, thunkAPI) =>
  {
  try 
  {
  const env: any = localStorage.getItem('environment');
  const token: any = "abcd";

  const model: any = {
    Token: "abcd",
    Environment: env,
  };

  alert(JSON.stringify(model));

  const response =   await axios({
      url: apiUrl,
      method: "get",
      data: model,
      headers:
      {
        'accept': 'text/plain',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')  || '{}')
      }
    })
    .then(response => 
    {            
        alert(JSON.stringify(response.data.resultData));
        return response.data.resultData;
    })
    .catch(error => 
      {
        alert(error.response.data);
      }); 

  return response;
} catch (e) 
{
  return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue("");
}
```

**Backend code:**

No need for something else except function declaration, since I am not going inside the code without needed values:

```
    [HttpGet, Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult<APIResponseBase<TokenDTO>>> GetTokenItems([FromQuery] TokenRequest filter)
```

**TokenRequest  model:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CompanyName.Models.API
{
public class TokenRequest
{
    public string? Token { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? Environment { get; set; }
}
}
```

Again, the code does access the needed function. But all values inside "filter" are nulls, empty strings, zeroes etc.

[image]

I do remember having similar problems before, but I can't pinpoint what causes this.

**What I checked:**

1. The first "alert" shows that "model" variable is generated correctly.
2. Of course I validated that variables in filter model and in frontend are the same.
3. I tried replacing "get" with "post" and vice versa.
4. I even tried renaming "model" to "filter".
5. Removing "FromQuery" from function declaration doesn't help too.
6. In inspect mode -> network I get the following:

[image]

[image]

I want to find what causes this, so next time I encounter something similar I won't have to guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send object with axios get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404051/send-object-with-axios-get-request)

Comment: Send a post request and read the data from request body (`FromBody` attribute).